# Is it possible to add a parameter/string to a custom-constructor/class downstream?

Tags: javascript

By "downstream" I mean outside of the custom-constructor later in the code.

i.e.

```
function Person (name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}
```

var me = new Person("Margo", 22);

I can add methods downstream to my custom-constructor/class (see example below):

```
person.prototype.sayName = function(){
console.log("Hi my name is " + margo.sayName + " .");
}
```

---

How do I add a parameter to the custom-constructor downstream that refers to a string, or boolean, etc?

The custom-constructor would technically be changed to

```
function Person (name, age, newParameter){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.newParameter = newParameter;
}
```

REMEMBER, I don't want to change the custom-constructor directly. I have posed this question to other programmers and they have answered it incorrectly by changing the original. The point is to change it outside("downstream") similar to adding a method by using prototype.